# How to put label with another way?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I am trying to draw this figure

[image]

I tried

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
        \path 
        (0,1) coordinate (a)
        (6,1) coordinate (A)
        (0,3) coordinate (b)
        (5,4) coordinate (B)
        ($(A)!0.5!(a)$) coordinate (M)
        ($(b)!0.5!(B)$) coordinate (N)
        ($(M)!0.5!(N)$) coordinate (c)
        ;
        \tkzDrawLine(a,A)
        \tkzDrawLine(b,B)
        \tkzDrawLine(M,N)   
        \foreach \p/\g in {a/-90,b/-90,c/0}{\path (\p)+(\g:3mm) node{$\p$};}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](B,N,M){$1$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](M,N,B){$3$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](b,N,M){$2$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](M,N,b){$4$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](b,N,M){$N$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](N,M,A){$M$}   
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](A,M,M){$4$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](N,M,A){$2$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](a,M,N){$3$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](N,M,a){$1$}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to put label `1, 2, 3, 4, M, N` with another way?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What is your desired output?

Comment: @SandyG Like my picture, can you do it with pure Tikz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure TikZ and mostly the `angles` library which provides the `angle` pic which I use with the `label angle` pic. When used, it forwards the argument to the `angle` pic but disables any drawing of angles and only places the text at the middle of the angle arc, the `angle eccentricity` is set to `1` so that the node is placed exactly `angle radius` away from the corner.

But before we can use it we need three points that define the corner.
Since you “overshoot” your lines, I'll define a `overshoot line` oic that draws a line extended at both ends about its third argment (after `:`) which can be either a ratio (say `0.1`) or a distance like `5mm`, the ratio uses the length between the two ends to calculate the length of the overshooting while the distance is taken literally.

With the same pic I'm also defining the new end points of this line with suffix `'` creating the coordinate `a'`, `A'`, `b`, `b'` (which we don't use) but also `M'` and `N'` which are needed for the angle labels.

Since I don't like some random letters along the a line I'm using the `dot` style and pins in the second very similar picture to place a dot at the place of the coordinates.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, angles, calc, quotes}
\tikzset{
  math mode/.style={execute at begin node=$, execute at end node=$},
  math labels/.style={every label/.append style=math mode},
  pics/label angle/.style={
    /tikz/path only, /tikz/angle eccentricity=1, angle/.expanded={#1}},
  pics/overshoot line/.style args={#1--#2:#3}{
    code=\path[pic actions]($(#1)!-(#3)!(#2)$) coordinate[name prefix ..] (#1')
               to[line to] ($(#2)!-(#3)!(#1)$) coordinate[name prefix ..] (#2');},
  pic nodes/.style ={every to/.append style={edge node={#1}}},
  pic nodes'/.style={every to/.append style={#1}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[math labels, angle radius=3.5mm]
\coordinate["a" below] (a) at (0,1) coordinate["A" below] (A) at (6,1)
 coordinate["b" above] (b) at (0,3) coordinate["B" above] (B) at (5,4);

\foreach \connA/\connB/\coord/\dist in {a/A/{"M" below, name=M}/5mm,
                                        b/B/{"N" above, name=N}/5mm,
                                        M/N/{"c" right, name=c}/0mm}
  \pic[draw, midway, label distance=\dist,
       pic nodes/.expanded={coordinate[\coord]}]
    {overshoot line = \connA--\connB:5mm};

\foreach[count=\i] \ang in {N'--N--b, b--N--M, M--N--B, B--N--N'}
  \pic[pic text=\i] {label angle=\ang};
\foreach[count=\i] \ang in {N--M--a, a--M--M', M'--M--A, A--M--N}
  \pic[pic text=\i] {label angle=\ang};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={shape=circle, fill, outer sep=+0pt, inner sep=+1pt},
  math labels, angle radius=3.5mm, pin distance=5mm,
  every pin edge/.append style={bend right=10, {Latex[round, scale=.75, sep]}-}]
\coordinate[dot, "a" below] (a) at (0,1) coordinate[dot, "A" below] (A) at (6,1)
 coordinate[dot, "b" above] (b) at (0,3) coordinate[dot, "B" above] (B) at (5,4);

\foreach \connA/\connB/\coord/\sett in {
  a/A/{dot, "M" below, name=M}/quotes mean pin,
  b/B/{dot, "N" above, name=N}/quotes mean pin,
  M/N/{dot, "c" right, name=c}/}
  \pic[draw, midway, style/.expand once=\sett,
       pic nodes/.expanded={coordinate[\coord]}]
    {overshoot line = \connA--\connB:5mm};

\foreach[count=\i] \ang in {N'--N--b, b--N--M, M--N--B, B--N--N'}
  \pic[pic text=\i] {label angle=\ang};
\foreach[count=\i] \ang in {N--M--a, a--M--M', M'--M--A, A--M--N}
  \pic[pic text=\i] {label angle=\ang};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]